# How would an anonymous class get GC'd in picasso on Android?

Tags: android, anonymous-inner-class, picasso

Can someone explain to me the [comment here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/38#issuecomment-23793609):

> Don't create anonymous class of Target when calling Picasso as might
>   get garbage collected. Keep a member field as a strong reference to
>   prevent it from being gc'ed

Per [line 30 of ImageViewAction.java](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/ImageViewAction.java), that Callback is a strong reference.

```
ImageViewAction(Picasso picasso, ImageView imageView, Request data, boolean skipCache,
      boolean noFade, int errorResId, Drawable errorDrawable, String key, Callback callback) {
    super(picasso, imageView, data, skipCache, noFade, errorResId, errorDrawable, key);
    this.callback = callback;
  }
```

Assuming the Callback is an anonymous class, it would create a reference to its parent class, thereby preventing the parent from being GC'd too.

Per [line 48 of Action.java](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Action.java), the target itself is a WeakReference, but that is not the callback.

```
  Action(Picasso picasso, T target, Request data, boolean skipCache, boolean noFade,
      int errorResId, Drawable errorDrawable, String key) {
    this.picasso = picasso;
    this.data = data;
    this.target = new RequestWeakReference<T>(this, target, picasso.referenceQueue);
```

Can someone explain what I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Someone must hold a reference to your `Target` otherwise it will get gc'ed because Picasso only stores a `WeakReference` to it.

Comment: Ah, I see - your comment only applied to the Target and not the Callback. It should be OK to use anonymous Callbacks then, yes?

Comment: Yes anonymous callbacks are kept as strong reference. It is HIGHLY recommended you invoke `cancel(target)` to free up the reference and prevent a temporary leak until Picasso download finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused and the comment referred to the Target (ImageView) not the Callback. The pattern of using an anonymous Callback is fine.