# First time error loading picture with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I have an `Activity` with an `ImagePagerAdapter` (extends of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`) that has this `getItem` method:

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "------------>mUserPicturesList.get("+position+").getFilename(): " + mUserPicturesList.get(position).getFilename());
            return UserDetailFragment.newInstance(mUserPicturesList.get(position).getFilename());
        }
```

The fragment that is instantiated has this onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate and locate the main ImageView
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_detail_fragment, container, false);
    mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mProgressPicturePager = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progress_picture_pager);

    String imageUrl = WApp.PHOTO_URL + mImageUrl + "?type=user_gallery_big_img";

    Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(getActivity());
    picasso.setDebugging(true);
    picasso.load(imageUrl)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.no_picture_man_big)
            .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
            .into(mImageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    mProgressPicturePager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Log.d(LOGTAG, "picasso load error");
                    mProgressPicturePager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

    return v;
}
```

**The Problem:**

When the `ImagePager` load first time, some times, Picasso call `onError`, showing the `.error` drawable.
If I press on back button and go back to the `Activity` that has the `ImagePager`, Picasso load the picture correctly.
If the `ImagePager` has two or more pictures and I swipe between the pictures, those are loaded correctly some times without exit and reenter to the `ImagePager`.

**The Theories:**

I think that it could be a problem of cache, but after many searches, I bet that the problem is in the weak reference of the Picasso.
Keep in mind that the problem only appears the FIRST TIME I load the activity that have the ImagePager.

In another place, currently `Picasso` works fine in `listView` with an adapter loading the pictures at first time. Calling `Picasso` inside the `getView` method of `Adapter` class.

**Visited links**

- [How would an anonymous class get GC'd in picasso on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505494/how-would-an-anonymous-class-get-gcd-in-picasso-on-android)
- [ViewPager unable to load images lazily with Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647533/viewpager-unable-to-load-images-lazily-with-picasso)
- http://square.github.io/picasso/
- https://plus.google.com/communities/109244258569782858265/stream/885843f4-c8b5-4851-9de1-b0374121dfa3
- [Use of Target in Picasso on Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199030/use-of-target-in-picasso-on-adapter)
- https://github.com/square/picasso/pull/349

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you attached a listener to your Picasso instance? You can print the stacktrace and see what the error was. Also what version of Picasso is this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved in the Picasso 2.3.0.

The fix is in the [Picasso changelog](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> Requests will now be automatically replayed if they failed due to network errors.

I hope this save you many hours.

Comment: I tried to update to the latest version of Picasso 2.3.2 in Android Studio v0.8.2 but it fails to sync the gradle project saying `Error:Failed to find: com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2`.  How do you fix this?

Comment: @toobsco42 try this line:

`compile group: 'com.squareup.picasso', name: 'picasso', version: '2.3.+'`

Comment: I found out it was an issue with permissions for files to be moved or deleted.  After fixing permission on the appropriate folders and cleaning the project then it all works now.