# Picasso doesn't download Image for First Time hosted on my company server?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, picasso

When the ImagePager load first time, some times, Picasso call onError, showing the .error drawable. If I press on back button and go back to the Activity that has the ImagePager, Picasso load the picture correctly. If the ImagePager has two or more pictures and I swipe between the pictures, those are loaded correctly some times without exit and reenter to the ImagePager.

***It correctly downloads other images from web. The issue arises when I tried to download from hosted company server.***

***I am using Picasso 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'.***

I also referred to below question but it doesn't help.

[First time error loading picture with Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890598/first-time-error-loading-picture-with-picasso)

***Below is my MainActivity.java***

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        configureToolbar(R.string.select_task);
        init();
    }

@Override
    protected void init() {
        //TODO: For QA Testing Purpose, Remove after Testing
        mWidthField =findViewById(R.id.edt_txt_1);
        mHeightField =findViewById(R.id.edt_txt_2);
        mImage=findViewById(R.id.image_view_2);
        mImageLoadButton=findViewById(R.id.image_load_button);
        item=new Item();
        item.setPrimaryImageURL("https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/190119161516-01-trump-government-shutdown-0119-exlarge-169.jpg");
        item.setUpc("0001111086751");
        Log.d("ImageManager","Main Activity");
        new ImageManager(getApplicationContext()).downloadImage(item.getPrimaryImageURL(),item.getUpc()+".jpeg",imageDownloadedCallBack);
        mImageLoadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadResizedImage();
            }
        });

    }


//TODO: For QA Testing Purpose, Remove after Testing
    ImageManager.ImageDownloadedCallBack imageDownloadedCallBack=new ImageManager.ImageDownloadedCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void imageDownloadComplete(final Bitmap bitmap, boolean status) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("ImageManager","Image Download CallBack in Main Activity");
                    mImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                }
            });
        }
    };
```

***Below is my ImageManager.java***

```
public class ImageManager {
    private final Context mContext;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;
    public ImageManager(Context mContext){
        this.mContext=mContext;
    }
    public interface ImageDownloadedCallBack {
        void imageDownloadComplete(Bitmap bitmap,boolean status);
    }

    private Target picassoImageTarget(Context context, final String imageDir, final String imageName,final ImageDownloadedCallBack imageDownloadedCallBack) {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
        final File directory = cw.getDir(imageDir, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_imageDir
        return new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        final File myImageFile = new File(directory, imageName);
                        FileOutputStream fos = null;
                        try {
                            fos = new FileOutputStream(myImageFile);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                            Log.d("ImageManager","Image DownLoad CallBack");
                            imageDownloadedCallBack.imageDownloadComplete(bitmap,true);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                fos.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                Log.d("ImageManager","Bitmap Failure");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                if (placeHolderDrawable != null) {}
            }
        };
    }

public void downloadImage(String url, String id,ImageDownloadedCallBack imageDownloadedCallBack){
//        this.imageDownloadedCallBack=imageDownloadedCallBack;
        Log.d("ImageManager","Download Image function");
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(picassoImageTarget(mContext,"imageDir", id ,imageDownloadedCallBack));

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe because of the image size is too big.

Comment: I have tried with different images with different sizes. But still I have the same issue no matter what the image size is.

Comment: One more reason would be that the PC hosting the image is slow or the connection to it is slow.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from old post and I implemented this code in MainActivity. And now it is working good.

```
final Target target = new Target{...};
imageView.setTag(target);
```

Refer wrb-answer below for the above code:

[wrb-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180805/onbitmaploaded-of-target-object-not-called-on-first-load)